# Difference between behavior and -ms-behavior

Tags: html, css, components, behavior

I don't understand the difference between `behavior` and `-ms-behavior`. I thought behavior was already only for Microsoft's Internet Explorer, so why is there a vendor prefix version?

Does it make any sense to use both or just `-ms-behavior`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Internet Explorer` **versions 5 and above** support the `behavior property`.

> **Internet Explorer Version 8** supports the syntactically correct Vendor Specific Extension format of-ms-behavior.

The majority of the time you only need `behavior`, unless you want to totally force `IE8 versions` to run in `standard mode`. Then you should use `ms-behavior`. But adding both doesn't hurt you at all and it probably is a good practice anyways.

Comment: So the main thing about css properities with a vendor prefix is that e.g. "behavior" is read by every browser even if they ignore it later. but e.g. "-ms-behavior" isnt even read by other browsers than IE. am I right about this?

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Internet Explorer 8**. The `-ms-behavior` attribute is an extension to CSS, and can be used as a **synonym for behavior** in **`IE8 Standards mode`**.

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530723(v=vs.85).aspx for more information